# Physical transformation associated with a Pseudo-Orthogonal matrix

Tags: symmetry, metric-tensor, group-theory, linear-algebra, matrix-elements

An orthogonal matrix $O$, which belongs to an orthogonal group, is characterized as $O^TO=I$.
Let's take an example of a $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrix, 
$$O = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \phantom{-} \cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta} \\
             -  \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}
    \end{bmatrix}, ........(1)$$
Physically, The matrix $O$ represents the rotational transformation, which describes the rotation in a 2D plane. This is well known among the researchers.

Now coming to less-popular Matrices/Group:

A pseudo-orthogonal matrix $\cal{D}$, which belongs to a pseudo-orthogonal group,  is characterized as $ \cal{D}^T \eta \cal{D}=\eta ,$ where $\eta$ is some constant metric.

Can anyone please give me a example of matrix $ \cal{D}$ like in Eq.(1)??.

What physical transformation represents the matrix $\cal{D}$ (e.g.  $O$ represents the rotation in 2D plane) ??.

Comment: If you are not familiar with the Poincar\'e or the conformal group, you can check that their generators have representations as pseudo-orthogonal matrices.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/84967).

Comment: @Sachin answers don't make questions on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After other's suggestions,

What I found is:

Orthogonal matrix $O$ (orthogonal group) which corresponds to a circular rotation. Similarly there exist a pseudo-orthogonal matrix $\cal D$ in pseudo orthogonal group, which corresponds to a  hyperbolic rotation.  $\cal D$ is as-

$$\cal D = \begin{bmatrix} 
    \phantom{-} \cosh{\theta} & \sinh{\theta} \\
              \sinh{\theta} & \cosh{\theta}
    \end{bmatrix},$$

which is pseudo-orthogonal as $\cal D^t \eta \cal D=\eta$, where $\eta$ = diag(1,-1).

Answer (score 3):

A well-known physical use of an [indefinite/pseudo orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) $O(p,q)$ is the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $O(n,1)$ in [SR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity).

Comment: also O(n,2) for the conformal group